# How to save Object[] with SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android

I tried many solutions, but nothing worked. I don't know if these are wrong, or just I'm doing something wrong. I have `MyClass[] array = new MyClass[] { objects declarations... };` and i want to save it with SharedPreferences. Can someone give me full `SaveIt() {}` and `LoadIt() {}` code necessary to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack overflow isn't a code-writing service. Please read the [ask] page for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

You can only store, simple values in SharedPrefences [SharePreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

**Update :**

**If you want use sideways library Use Gson Library:**

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

**Store:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//Your json response object value store in json object
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
//Convert json object to string
String json = gson.toJson(jsonObject);
//Store in the sharedpreference
getPrefs().setUserJson(json);
```

**Retrieve:**

```
String json = getPrefs().getUserJson();
```

Comment: Isnt it possible using Gson? And I want to save class which i did myself.

Comment: But what is definition of 'response' and 'getPrefs'?

Comment: i added codes for **store** and **retrieve**, use them

Comment: I used it, but i don't have defined 'response' and 'getPrefs()' and when i try compile this i gets error "Cannot resolve symbol 'response'"

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreference` is not built to store complex object, array or list.

So in your case, I suggest using [Realm](https://www.realm.io/) or SQLite as a local database. You can add, remove, or query list of items, which is more flexible

Comment: Ok, thanks, if i wont find way to do this with SharedPreference i will try Realm :)